# How does Facebook prevent the downloading of GIF images when using "SafeImage.php"?

Tags: html, facebook, animated-gif, copy-protection

[Here is an example](https://www.facebook.com/BerningHeartsClub/posts/1839451852991912?pnref=story) of a GIF image that is cached on Facebook.  This GIF has a "launcher" that requires a user to click the image to proceed.

This is a static JPEG created by Facebook's safeimage process.

Once I click the Image, I'm not able to download the underlying GIF.

What browser feature is FB taking advantage of to cause this copy protection to occur?

Comment: The don't use GIF, they convert it to video.

Comment: All Gifs are converted to video? https://www.facebook.com/gifporn1/ @cbroe

Comment: Yes, they are. Easy enough to verify using your browser's dev tools. For this post https://www.facebook.com/gifporn1/posts/402844106720956, here is the actual video URL that gets played when you click the button: https://video-vie1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t42.4659-2/14968782_974193562686743_3177796643898523648_n.mp4?oh=847a6d20634ddc38c9581f8d6ffd60ac&oe=581BB402 (the latter might of course stop working at some point, as FB CDN URLs do.)